# ✗ 'shopify node serve' leads to - ngrok tunnel has timed out, restarting…

Tags: shopify, ngrok

Whenever I run shopify node serve i get a response saying
✗ ngrok tunnel has timed out, restarting…
✗ ngrok tunnel could not be stopped. Try running killall -9 ngrok
killall -9 ngrok
No matching processes belonging to you were found.

$ shopify node tunnel stop
x ngrok tunnel not running

I have tried deleting ngrok.pid and ngrok.log files and removing the entire ngrok folder in shopify cache folder , still wont work

Comment: Your question text, as currently formatted, is a bit difficult to read. Please consider editing your question to add some text formatting to differentiate between the commands and output (error messages), etc.

Answer (score 0):

There was an issue that has been fixed in the latest release of shopify-cli ([2.7.1](https://github.com/Shopify/shopify-cli/releases/tag/v2.7.1)). You can find more details [here](https://github.com/Shopify/shopify-cli/pull/1758).